# Finding longest word, passing 9/10 tests, Why?

Tags: javascript

This is an task from [codesignal](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-12/s9qvXv4yTaWg8g4ma).
It's not a homework or something else, just I writed a code and now trying understand what's wrong.
Let's see task requirements.
Define a *word* as a sequence of consecutive English letters. Find the longest *word* from the given string.

**Example.**

For **`text = "Ready, steady, go!"`**, the output should be
**`solution(text) = "steady"`**.

Well, now I'm sharing my code.

```
function solution(text) {
 let words = text.match(/\w+/g);
    
    let ml = Math.max(...words.map(el=>el.length))
    
    for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(words[i].length == ml){
            return words[i]
        }
    }
}
```

It's passing all tests, except of one hide test. Now I opened that hide test  it looks like this **`text: "ab-CDE-fg_hi"`.**  Expected output of this test is `"CDE"` .
Now I'm trying understand what's the problem and why it's not passing this test, can someone please *explain* me.

I'm nebie so please be polite)

Comment: If you run it with the failing input, it gives "fg_hi". Does that look right to you? It does that because `\w` [includes underscore](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp). (also numbers which you probably don't want either)

Comment: @DanielHakobyan In order for a question to be a "good" question you basicly have to follow 3 Steps. 1. Try to understand what goes wrong with your code. 2. Research for that specific problem. 3. After research failed, ask a question.

The volks here believe, that you skipped the first 2 steps, therefore downvoting your question. By using a debugger or console.logs, you could have easily spottet that "fg_hi" is included in your matching list. So the problem would be broken down from "Why?" to "What does \w+ actually match". And this is probably something you would have found by googling it

Comment: You are telling me a very long story, so I will not read this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\w+/` also includes an underscore, try to make the regex more precise, for example `/[A-Za-z0-9]+/`:

```js
function solution(text) {
 let words = text.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/g);
    
    let ml = Math.max(...words.map(el=>el.length))
    
    for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(words[i].length == ml){
            return words[i]
        }
    }
}

console.log(solution("ab-CDE-fg_hi"));
```

You could also iterate the words immediately and find your max sooner:

```js
function solution(text) {
  let max = '';
  for(const word of text.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/g)){
    if(max.length < word.length){
      max = word;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(solution("ab-CDE-fg_hi"));
```

Btw you can split instead of match:

```js
function solution(text) {
  let max = '';
  for(const word of text.split(/[\s\W_]+/g)){
    if(max.length < word.length){
      max = word;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(solution("ab-CDE-fg_hi"));
```

Comment: As an addition, consider iterating the array only once for better peformance: `function solution(text) { return text.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi).reduce((acc, cur) => cur.length > acc.length ? cur : acc) }`

Comment: @DanielHakobyan `Array::reduce()` could be advanced for a newbee, added a simpler solution to the answer